# How to consume yield results fetched one by one by database on demand from an API end point? Are web sockets needed?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, graph-databases, yield

I am thinking of setting up a page in an application that each of the queries can return a resultset that cannot fit in memory or the query is very expensive to fetch all of them. The user will be hitting "get more" to get more of those results. I wonder if I could use a yielder for Java something like that (http://benjiweber.co.uk/blog/2015/03/21/yield-return-in-java/) and if I will need Web Sockets e.g from Spring (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html) so that the client can tell to Server to push more results. Also could you please give an example of the handshake .. Will the endpoint uri be based on some session id as well? Also when databases like OrientDB/Neo4j return Iterables does it mean that we can keep the connection open and get the next rows after minutes without problems? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about two different concepts.

**Pagination**

If you have a large result set and you need to return it piece by piece to avoid long query times or high memory requirements, you're paginating the over the result set.

To do this, you require another piece of the set hitting "Get More" button from the client. Each time you require more, the server will receive a request from the server and will hit the DB with some paginated query.

Example in SQL (page 10, 10 results/page , for instance):

```
SELECT * FROM Table OFFSET 100 LIMIT 109
```

**Websockets / Yielder**

You'll need a websocket / yielder when is the server the one who sends data, in other words, the client doesn't require an update, it only keeps the socket open and receives updates from the Server when they come. 
That's the case of a Message service, for example, avoiding constant polling from the client side.

In your case is absolutely unnecessary a websocket. You can also see an example of what I'm saying here -> [What's the behavioral difference between HTTP Stay-Alive and Websockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620620/whats-the-behavioral-difference-between-http-stay-alive-and-websockets)

However you can setup a `keep-alive` connection between your back-end and database in order to avoid closing/opening constantly the connection each time the user requires more results.

Finally, your question about Iterable results in Neo4j. Neo4j's result type is an `Iterable` list of `Map<String,Object>` which represents a List of key-value pairs. That doesn't keep the connection alive (by default), it only iterates through the returned results of that particular query.

Comment: In order for pagination to work the resultset size should be known.. in graph databases that we are talking about traversals the resultset size is unknown .. So this doesn't answer my question..I would like to implement something like the timeline of facebook that could be hundreds of GB or TB to get it all for a user. I would use websockets so that the client can send back to the server a message that needs more...

Comment: Actually you don't need to know the size of the resultset since your pagination is using SKIP and LIMIT (neo4j case), which is the way facebook or twitter paginate. You keep getting chunks of data until you run out.

Comment: well what happens each time you skip though? internally it iterates all those traversals.. and skips them... so each query should be getting slower even if the amount of data is the same ... am I wrong? I just want the cursor to be there and reiterate from the start somehow..

Comment: It depends on the moment you decide to SKIP, so you may not need to get the entire result set if you SKIP on time. However, even if you don't use skip I don't see any other way of getting a new chunk of data ignoring the one you have except skipping or filtering it out. Anyhow I don't see how a websocket could help you in this case. That's intended for incoming data rather than retrieving existing data.

Comment: That's why I am saying I want to do a ```select * from X```` and for each let's say 10 rows yield the result to the client.. Then if and when the client wants more, I go back to the loop and fetch the next 10 rows.... That was why I posted this question :)

Comment: Ok, I got you wrong. I think what you need is something like Hibernate's Scrollable Result - http://java.dzone.com/articles/bulk-fetching-hibernate

Comment: I found this intresting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169615/spring-batch-itemreader-with-scrollable-resultset